# How to change ctrl+right/left navigate shortcuts in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, shortcuts, macbuntu

How can I change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>, but keep all Ctrl-related shortcuts unchanged (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume now that you need this key shortcuts with readline, as used in a terminal.

To get an overview you can ether take a look at

```
less /etc/inputrc
```

or use the command bind to see your active bindkeys:

```
bind -P
```

To change this seetings I propose to use the local `.inputrc`file in your home directory; maybe it even does not exists now.

Therefore you have to say for which purpose you would like to change the key shortcut. Is it **forward** one word?

In case you want to change **forward/backward word** properties, you can do:

```
echo "\"\e[C\": forward-word" >> ~/.inputrc
echo "\"\e[D\": backward-word" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Open a new terminal an try it.

If you need a more detailed answer you have to put more specific information to your post.

Comment: There's no such shortcut. Maybe you can say the name?

Comment: can you specify more details; do yo need this shortcuts in a terminal?

Comment: No, I need the shortcuts in the whole system. Inside browsers, applications, notepad, etc.