# how to customize ubuntu terminal shortcut of deleting a word backward and forward

Tags: command-line, unity, shortcut-keys

this may seem as a duplicate question, but I couldn't find a solution in others, I am using Ubuntu 18.04 for now, and the terminal shortcut of deleting a word backward and forward is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, but I am more used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, I don't see any shortcut option for this editting operation in `dconf editor`, is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**
I tried `echo '"\C-\b":kill-word' >> .inputrc` but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change ctrl+right/left navigate shortcuts in ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058752/how-to-change-ctrlright-left-navigate-shortcuts-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: sorry, I still couldn't figure out how to do this, I tried `echo '"\C-\b":kill-word' >> .inputrc` but it didn't work